# Comparing start/end dates between different rows based on common data field

Tags: sas

SAS 9.4

Example dataset

```
╔═════════╦═══════╦════════════╦══════════╗  
║ subject ║ event ║ start_date ║ end_date ║  
╠═════════╬═══════╬════════════╬══════════╣  
║ s1      ║ e1    ║ 2-Mar-19   ║ 1-Jun-19 ║  
║ s2      ║ e1    ║ 1-Mar-19   ║ 1-May-19 ║  
╚═════════╩═══════╩════════════╩══════════╝
```

Expected Output:

```
╔═════════╦═══════╦════════════╦══════════╦════════════╗  
║ subject ║ event ║ start_date ║ end_date ║ query_text ║  
╠═════════╬═══════╬════════════╬══════════╬════════════╣   
║ s1      ║ e1    ║ 1-Mar-19   ║ 1-Jun-19 ║ error?     ║  
║ s2      ║ e1    ║ 1-Mar-19   ║ 1-May-19 ║ error?     ║  
╚═════════╩═══════╩════════════╩══════════╩════════════╝
```

I want to return all that have the same 'event' and where the 'end_date' of one with the earlier 'start_date' is greater than (>) the 'start_date' of the other one with the later start_date.

Here, subject 's2' has an earlier 'start_date' than 's1' but 's2' has a later 'end_date' than "s1's" 'start_date', so these two would get returned

This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure how to make sure what I'm comparing have the same 'event':

```
data Out_2;   
/* set relevant dataset */   
if input(compress(end_date,"/"), ??date9.) > input(compress(start_date,"/"), ??date9.);  

/* do something */  

run;
```

Thanks

Comment: Is the `1-Mar-19` start_date for `s1` in the expected output a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to process rows in groups in a DATA step is to sort by the key, then use `BY key_field` (`event` in your example) in the DATA step, `retain`ing the data from the previous rows in a group, while identifying the group's first and last row using `if first.key_field` and `if last.key_field`).

That would be easy if you have a maximum of two subjects per event. If you have more you'd have to write duplicate code to retain the values from the first, second, etc rows, or retain the data into an array.

So I'd ditch the DATA step in favor of SQL, which lets you do this easily:

```
proc sql;
    create table result as
    select i1.*
      from example_input i1,
           example_input i2
     where i1.event = i2.event
       and i1.subject ^= i2.subject
       and (
             (i1.start_date < i2.start_date and
              i1.end_date > i2.start_date
             ) 
           or /* the other way around */
             (i2.start_date < i1.start_date and
              i2.end_date > i1.start_date
             )
           )
   ; /* untested - I don't have SAS handy */
quit;
```

The output I get with this SQL on your input data (not in SAS, but I'm pretty sure it shouldn't give different results!):

```
| subject | event | start_date | end_date   |
| ------- | ----- | ---------- | ---------- |
| s1      | e1    | 2019-03-02 | 2019-06-01 |
| s2      | e1    | 2019-03-01 | 2019-05-01 |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ti8fHnpAqnDc56KM8NfShg/0)

Comment: Hmm thanks for the reply! It seems like this code almost gets me there, but the Select i1.* just gives me duplicates. But after using Distinct, it also gives me single entries (using the OP as example, it would just give me subject s1 but not subject s2). I would like to have subject s1 and s2 returned

Comment: Huh, do you really mean duplicates? On the exact example data set you've provided (assuming it has "SAS date values", not strings in start_date and end_date)? I'm curious what i1.*, i2.* outputs then. // I've checked that SQL itself is doing what I intended it to do and added a link to SQLFiddle.

Comment: Oh wait, no yeah, your code works, I'm not sure why I was getting duplicates last night. The output seems right even though my date format is like "05JAN2019" or is this a format that SQL can do date comparison in? Thanks!

Comment: Regarding date values, ensure that the date variables in your dataset have numeric, not character type. If they do, you see "05JAN2019" because a `DATE9.` format is defined on the date columns; most SAS code, including the one I posted, operates on unformatted values ([SAS date values](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/65287/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1wj0wt2ebe2a0n1lv4lem9hdc0v.htm)) - so date comparison will work as expected.