# How to subset data and set values based on matching dates

Tags: sas

I have a table like:

**id**  --  **date** ------------ **value**

x   ---   01/01/2019    ----      1

y  ---    01/01/2019    ----      2

x ---     01/02/2019    ----      1

z ---    01/03/2019     ----      1

I am trying to select `where id in (x,y)`

Then, once I have that subset, I want to check if x has a corresponding y of the same date

- if it does, then I want to set `new` to `value` from the row with this date and `id=y` - for both x and y;
- otherwise, `new` is just set to `value`

so the table would become

**id**  --  **date** ------------ **value**   --    **new**

x   ---   01/01/2019    ----      1      --------      2

y  ---    01/01/2019    ----      2      --------      2

x ---     01/02/2019    ----      1      --------      1

z ---    01/03/2019     ----      1      --------      1

I am totally unsure how to go about this,

I began by subsetting my data:

```
IF id='x' OR id='y' THEN DO;

/*...*/

END;

ELSE new=value;
```

any help would be appreciated

Also, I cannot use the actual dates in my code
I don't need to generalize the id, I know specifically that I need to be comparing/ checking x and y (y is a follow up for x in the data I am using)

Comment: It is not at all clear what your criteria is for you new variable. Is it the value for the X record, the Y record, the "other" record of the pair, the MAX() value or the MIN() value?

Answer (score 0):

I've recently [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56745331/1026) a similar question. Base SAS isn't very convenient for problems like this - solving it with DATA steps involves sorting in the right order, then reading in `BY` groups, and `retain`ing the data across rows.

This is easier in SQL: the expected result you've described can be obtained by LEFT JOINing the original table (T) with a subset (Y) of itself (where id=y) on `date`. Once joined, `new` can be calculated as `coalesce(Y.value, T.value)`